# Tag rename request: eshop -> nintendo-eshop

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I noticed we have the tag [eshop](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eshop) today with a recent question. At first, I thought it was a meta tag that needed removing, but when I looked closer, it does indeed specifically refer to the Nintendo shop. In order to have perfectly clear tagging, I propose the tag be renamed to [nintendo-eshop](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-eshop).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreed. I've deleted [eshop](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eshop) and created [nintendo-eshop](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-eshop).